# Best practices for AJAX UI buttons and actions?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, user-interface, single-page-application

I'm moving from a traditional client-server website app (where a page refresh will show the action happening and show an updated page or an error), to an AJAX UI (using angularjs).

One of my concerns is how to properly convey to the user that the action has been submitted, and that it was either a success or failure.

E.g. if the user hits several buttons in a row, each one changing state, how do I best:

1. Show the user that the click happened. Do I change the state at once to assume success?  Or do I wait until I get a successful reply and then update it?  The latter is not a responsive (quick) UI.

Another option would be to show a modal loading dialog when the button is pressed, but this is also not desired because the user has to wait between each click.

2. Show the user an error. Assuming they have pressed several buttons before the error of the first one is returned.  They might even have that button outside the view at this point.
3. Handle timed out or dropped requests. Is there a builtin (in jquery or angularja) low timeout and retry that will avoid unnecessary error messages?
4. Highlight the successfully updated state. I've read that users sometimes get confused when the action happens without a page flash/refresh; "did it save or do anything..?"

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say all this depends on what the action actually is.

Comment: I would take a guess that this question is not suited for SO.

Comment: can't you change the style of each button when clicked? for example if the user clicks on a button, the button's text changes to "please wait" and the opacity changes to 0.75 and when the response is ready, the button turns to green or red to indicate the response.